# Remove blank space from data frame column values in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame (`business_df`) of schema:

```text
|-- business_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- categories: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- full_address: string (nullable = true)
|-- hours: struct (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to make a new data frame (`new_df`) so that the values in the `'name'` column do not contain any blank spaces.

My code is:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''), StringType())
new_df = business_df.select(*[udf(column).alias(name) if column == name else column for column in business_df.columns])
new_df.registerTempTable("vegas")
new_df.printSchema()
vegas_business = sqlContext.sql("SELECT stars, name from vegas limit 10").collect()
```

I keep receiving this error:

> NameError: global name 'replace' is not defined

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What's wrong?  As far as I can tell it cannot be used to reproduce the problem :) Are you sure this is the code you use? Error you report suggests that you use unbounded `replace` somewhere. This approach is also rather inefficient but it is completely different story.

Comment: @zero323 What would you do, instead? I would have created some `UDF`s also :(

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto It depends on the logic. It is not clear if OP wants to any spaces alone (this is what happens) here or blank lines. One way or another it can be easily done without Python batch job.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While the problem you've described is not reproducible with provided code, using Python `UDFs` to handle simple tasks like this, is rather inefficient. If you want to simply remove spaces from the text use `regexp_replace`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "foo bar"), (2, "foobar "), (3, "   ")
]).toDF(["k", "v"])

df.select(regexp_replace(col("v"), " ", ""))
```

If you want to normalize empty lines use `trim`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim

df.select(trim(col("v")))
```

If you want to keep leading / trailing spaces you can adjust `regexp_replace`:

```
df.select(regexp_replace(col("v"), "^\s+$", ""))
```

Comment: what I want to do is related to my previous post that you answered about sql select statements and bind variables. For this question, the set-up is the same as before: I have a list of restaurants and their cities e.g. [[Le Bernadin, Manhattan][...,...]] that I would like to loop through and retrieve matching restaurants from a data frame that contains data following the schema above. However, because the blank spaces are producing errors, I want to eliminate these spaces from the data frame queried data so that I can compare the single word strings such as 'LeBernadin'

Comment: the regex solution does seem better, however when I run it the df schema is replaced with the regex expression (root |-- regexp_replace(name,[\s'():^],): string (nullable = true)). I'm a bit puzzled, know why this is?

Comment: Because you don't use aliases. If you want a specific name use withColumn or alias.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function that removes all whitespace in a string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def remove_all_whitespace(col):
    return F.regexp_replace(col, "\\s+", "")
```

You can use the function like this:

```
actual_df = source_df.withColumn(
    "words_without_whitespace",
    quinn.remove_all_whitespace(col("words"))
)
```

The `remove_all_whitespace` function is defined in the [quinn library](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn).  quinn also defines `single_space` and `anti_trim` methods to manage whitespace.  PySpark defines `ltrim`, `rtrim`, and `trim` methods to manage whitespace.

Comment: As I said, my experience with *regex_replace* was not good because is too slow! I had a better performance using *rdd.map*

Comment: @AndreCarneiro, can you share your revised code with rdd.map that you found faster than using regex.. i am trying to do some checking on UK postal codes and regexp is taking a very long time to process

Comment: @AndreCarneiro - I don't think your code would run faster than a `regexp_replace`.  Native Spark functions visible by the compilers so they can be optimized in execution plans.  It's possible my understanding of Spark is off, but I don't think so :)

Comment: @EB Well, if you never tried it you'll never know! Feel confortable to make a 'benchmark' if you want to! I'll do it when I can. For now, this solved my problems! So, it was good enough for me!

Answer (score 4):

As @zero323 said, it's probably that you overlapped the `replace` function somewhere. I tested your code and it works perfectly.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("aaa 111",), ("bbb 222",), ("ccc 333",)], ["names"])
spaceDeleteUDF = udf(lambda s: s.replace(" ", ""), StringType())
df.withColumn("names", spaceDeleteUDF("names")).show()

#+------+
#| names|
#+------+
#|aaa111|
#|bbb222|
#|ccc333|
#+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @Powers there is a very nice and easy to read function to remove white spaces provided by a package called quinn.You can find it here: https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn Here are the instructions on how to install it if working on a Data Bricks workspace: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html

Here again an illustration of how it works:

```
#import library 
import quinn

#create an example dataframe
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "foo bar"), (2, "foobar "), (3, "   ")
]).toDF(["k", "v"])

#function call to remove whitespace. Note, withColumn will replace column v if it already exists
df = df.withColumn(
    "v",
    quinn.remove_all_whitespace(col("v"))
)
```

The output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that solution using regexp_replace too slow even for few data! So I've tried to find another way and I think I found it!

Not beaultiful, little naive, but it's fast! What do you think?

```
def normalizeSpace(df,colName):

  # Left and right trim
  df = df.withColumn(colName,ltrim(df[colName]))
  df = df.withColumn(colName,rtrim(df[colName]))

  #This is faster than regexp_replace function!
  def normalize(row,colName):
      data = row.asDict()
      text = data[colName]
      spaceCount = 0;
      Words = []
      word = ''

      for char in text:
          if char != ' ':
              word += char
          elif word == '' and char == ' ':
              continue
          else:
              Words.append(word)
              word = ''

      if len(Words) > 0:
          data[colName] = ' '.join(Words)

      return Row(**data)

      df = df.rdd.map(lambda row:
                     normalize(row,colName)
                 ).toDF()
      return df
schema = StructType([StructField('name',StringType())])
rows = [Row(name='  dvd player samsung   hdmi hdmi 160W reais    de potencia 
bivolt   ')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df = normalizeSpace(df,'name')
df.show(df.count(),False)
```

That prints

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|name                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|dvd player samsung hdmi hdmi 160W reais de potencia|
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @Andrei Carneiro,  if I understand your function you would just append one space in the string and replace anything with more than 1 space as long as it is not leading or trailing space correct?

Comment: Yes! But the same principle can be applied! But I realize that `regexp_replace` is the best solution for this problem. I think was foolished by my VM. Something like: `df = df.withColumn(colName,regexp_replace( df[colName] r"\s+","")`