# Removing comma in a column in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark

I have two columns first and Second in my DataFrame. Both columns contains empty cells

```
    | **ID**    First    |Second|
    |----------|---------|------|
    |   1      |    Toys |      |
    |          |         |      |
    |--------------------|------|
    |   2      |         | Jeans| 
    |--------------------|------|
    |   3      |Jeans    |Shirt |
    -----------------------------
```

I concatenated the two columns into a new column using

> df=df.select('ID',concat(col("First"),  lit(","),col("Second")).alias('ITEM'))

```
    |----------|----------------|
    | **ID**    **ITEM**        |
    |----------|----------------|
    |   1      |    Toys,       |
    |          |                |
    |---------------------------|
    |   2      |    ,Jeans      | 
    |---------------------------|
    |   3      |Jeans,Shirt     |
    -----------------------------
```

I need to remove the comma so that I can calculate the TF-IDF of each row in the DataFrame. For this purpose I am splitting the string list in each row to a word list on the basis of the comma.

```
    |----------|----------------|
    | **ID**    **ITEM**        |
    |----------|----------------|
    |   1      |    [Toys, ]    |
    |          |                |
    |---------------------------|
    |   2      |   [ ,Jeans]    | 
    |---------------------------|
    |   3      |[Jeans,Shirt]   |
    -----------------------------
```

Now, HashingTF is considering the empty space as a term, which is giving me an incorrect TF-IDF score.
I have looked into the following link for removing the `,`
[Remove blank space from data frame column values in spark python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540974/remove-blank-space-from-data-frame-column-values-in-spark-python)
and also tried

```
df.select(regexp_replace(col("ITEM"), ",", "")).show()
```

which removes the comma and but then I am unable to split on the basis of comma.

I have also tried to used udf

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

commaRep = udf(lambda x: x.replace(',^\s+$',''))

df=df.withColumn('ITEMS',commaRep('ITEM'))
```

which has no effect.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, concat, col, lit
import re

commaRep = udf(lambda x: re.sub(',$|^,','', x))
df=df.select('ID',concat(col("First"), lit(","),col("Second")).alias('ITEM'))
df=df.withColumn('ITEMS',commaRep('ITEM'))
df.show(3)
```

The main changes to the above suggestion were:

- use `re` module
- remove comma at beginning or end of string

Answer (score 0):

I can sort of see where this is coming from but normally we would need more info or more of your source code to see the real issue. But somewhere inside your code is a misplaced or a left out ". As your program iterates through it self it is coded to add those commas if you are adding code to go back and remove those commas after the fact you are adding unnecessary code.

Go back through your source code and look at all your print commands that populate these areas where your finding unnecessary commas OR post more of your source code so I can find it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I have merged two columns using lit(','). I have edited th question. Could you kindly look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

commaRep = udf(lambda x: x.replace(u',^\s+$',''))
```

or

```
def removefromend(x):  
          for i in [',']:  
                  if x.endswith(i):  
                          token = x.replace(i,'')  
                          return token  
         return x
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it, but it has no effect.

Comment: I think the issue with this is that there is no space between the comma and the end of the text

Comment: @abhinavchoudhury  try this.