# How do i replace whitespace with underscore and encode values in scala array / list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark scala dataframe which has column "Name"
I have extracted the values of that column in to scala array[string]

```
org_name: Array[String] = Array(SARATOGA SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL)
```

I want to replace whitespaces with _  and encode that value in to utf-8 (any encoding is fine as long as it replaces special chars with something else)
so if there are any special chars those will be removed. later i want to use those in file path .

```
var org_name = orgsFlatDF.rdd.collect
.map( _.getString(2))
```

This is how i am extracting those vals ^^. I haven't found any method which I can use to do that. Replace or replaceall doesn't work on array

I tried this :

```
org_name.replace("\\s", "")
```

That didn't work .

Expected output : SARATOGA_SENIOR_HIGH_SCHOOL

if name is : `new $ high school` it should gets converted to `new_$_high_school` then encoded to `new_%24_high_school`

Comment: try regex_replace here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540974/remove-blank-space-from-data-frame-column-values-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with what you are asking.

Java/Scala Arrays don't have a replace method. Even if they did have a replace method, would they replace the values they hold or the characters in a String they hold?

Let's assume this line `org_name.replace("\\s", "")` didn't compiled and org_name is indeed a an Array[String] holding one element.

```
scala> val org_name=Array("SARATOGA SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL")
val org_name: Array[String] = Array(SARATOGA SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL)
scala> org_name(0).replace(" ","_")
val res15: String = SARATOGA_SENIOR_HIGH_SCHOOL
```

`replace("\\s","_")` wouldn't work because it represents a `\s` string. "\" represents `\`. That's only way you'd be able to define strings containing other escape codes like `\n` or `\t`.

PS: to transform all the string in the array use `org_name.map(_.replace(" ","_"))`, this gives you back another another array.

Comment: Thank You so much I will look in to it .