# PySpark dataframe remove white-spaces from a column of the string

Tags: regex, dataframe, pyspark

Here in this pic, column Values contains some string values where the spaces are there in between, hence I am unable to convert this column to an Integer type.
If you can help me remove this white space from these string values, I can then cast them easily.
[image: pic1]

I have tried`df_cause_death_france.select(regexp_replace(col("Value")," ",""))`
It does works but it removes all other columns from my spark dataframe.

[image: pic2]

Comment: Please, add your code directly instead of an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove blank space from data frame column values in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540974/remove-blank-space-from-data-frame-column-values-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

please ignore this question. I am able to solve it.

In case you want to know my solution, here it is.

`df_cause_death_france.withColumn('VALUE', regexp_replace('Value', ' ','')).show()`

output =
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bljf.png

Comment: FYI, it is perfectly fine to answer your own questions. No need to "ignore" it.

Comment: yup. I am learning it. Many more such questions to follow.